# xapges navigator not showing

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Another hopefully simple issue from an xpages beginner.

I am trying to use the Navigator control from the Extension Library. No matter what I do with it, I cannot get it to render on any of the pages I try it on. Code is below. Thanks for any assistance.

`<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xe:navigator id="outline" expandable="true">
        <xe:this.treeNodes>
            <xe:pageTreeNode page="/bcbsarequirements.xsp" selection="/bcbsarequirements" label="BCBSA Requirements" role="navigation"/>
            <xe:pageTreeNode page="/compliance.xsp" selection="/compliance" role="navigation" label="Compliance"/>
            <xe:pageTreeNode page="/finance.xsp" selection="/finance" label="Finance" role="navigation"/>
        </xe:this.treeNodes>
    </xe:navigator>
    </xp:view>`

Comment: is there any error on the console?

Comment: Are you trying to render on the Server or client? If the server, does the server have UP1 installed? In Application properties is the ext lib library referenced. Lastly check the XPages*.log files in the IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder of where they are being rendered for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This will happen at least if your view tag is missing the extension library attribute. Make sure the view tag looks like this: `<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">`. If the attribute is missing there is an error visible in the source.
2. Make sure there is no error in XPage source.
3. Make sure the application is built (sometimes project -> clean is needed).
4. Make sure extension library is checked in application properties (you should get errors if not).
5. Check for any error messages in the server console/log when loading the XPage on browser.
6. Do other extension library controls render for you? If not there is a problem in ExtLib installation.
7. Make sure your Designer and server have the same and preferably the latest (20121217) ExtLib version.
8. If you are using the *Upgrade Pack* then you can open an SPR with IBM.

Comment: both of those xml references are on the view elemenet. I added my xp:view to the original post

Comment: @JimM I added more possible reasons to my answer.

Comment: No errors at all in designer, project is set to auto build ,but I unset that, cleaned and built again, extlib is selected in the advanced properties, no errors on server console or browser window, and other controls for the extlib do render(I am using application layout, form table, form column, and form row)

Comment: @JimM Added one more item to my answer.

Comment: @PanuHarramo, they botha re the same version installed at the same time from the same 8.5.3 upgrade pack from IBM Passport

Comment: @JimM OK, upgrade pack is 2011 version of ExtLib. Your code works for me with the latest ExtLib. One reason could be that there is a bug in the old ExtLib. The good thing about Upgrade Pack is that you can open an SPR with IBM.

Comment: Thanks for all of the assistance. I will open an SPR. I am going to rebuiild my dev environment and look into that as well.

Comment: Just an update for anyone interested. I tried this on my dev environment at the office and it worked. So on my dev environment at home I updated the extlib to the latest from OpenNTF on both designer and server and navigator works great. Many thanks Panu!!